# Hive import not taking place using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to import mysql to hive but it's not happening with the below query
:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/cars --username root --query 'Select carnum,carname from carsinfo where $CONDITIONS' --hive-import --hive-table exams.examresults --target-dir /hive_table1_data --m 1
```

I am getting the error while importing saying

> Encoutered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException.

i really don't understand what's the mistake I am doing. Hours I have spent on this. But nothing seems to work.

Thanks !!

Comment: There are several things that could be happening here. **1)** Ensure MySQL is running **2)** The address for it is correct **3)** The credentials for it are correct **4)** The query is correct (for example, what is `$CONDITIONS`?) **5)**  The Hive target directory is empty or non-existant

Comment: Please refer this : http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/importing-data-into-hive-with-sqoop.html

Comment: 1. You didn't specify -P or --password. How are you giving the password?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to specify the port.
Try this: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars' this of course, makes an assumption that you're running mysql on the default port.

Comment: Can you post the entire stack-trace?